# How to release windows build of ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, ionic-view

I am trying to release windows build of ionic app used below two command **ionic platform add windows**  and **ionic build windows** but at the time of run second command getting following error at cmd

D:\@Ionic\ChefsRecipes>ionic build windows
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\@Ionic\ChefsRecipes\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\@Ionic\ChefsRecipes
add to body class: platform-windows
Error: No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target.

I have set PATH variable to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;". I am using windows 8.0 please suggest me right step for release build for windows ?

Comment: have you follow https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html ?

Comment: fyi: for developing windows build you at least need 8.1 pro or windows 10. I have windows 10 which works like charm for cordova windows phone build.

Comment: Thanks @Naitik for your response . I can work on windows 10, so please  describe the steps which should i follow. or it's compulsory to use visual studio ?

Comment: Please follow official https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html site

Comment: and for your question "it's compulsory to use visual studio ?" - yes it's better use visual studio as it's also give on official documentation...